# Send build artifacts over SSH - could not create directory

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I am trying to workout an automation process of pushing changes from jenkins to aws. The problem seems to be that within the GIT repo, i have 2 folders, one is `docroot` and the other is `database`. I need the `docroot` to go into the `/var/www/html` and database should be ignored for now.

As a trial run, i am trying the following settings:

**Settings 1:**

Post-build Actions

Under transfer set

```
Source files: **/*
Remove prefix: empty
Remote directory: empty
Exec command: pwd
```

Result:
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Could not create or change to directory. Directory [database]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE

**Settings 2**:

Post-build Actions

Under transfer set

```
Source files: **/*
Remove prefix: empty
Remote directory: /var/www/html
Exec command: pwd
```

Result:
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Could not create or change to directory. Directory [var]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE

All the errors seem to be revolving around creation of a directory - but i dont need to create one...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the plugin you are using for this step is [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) which seems to be the case the first point of call would be to enable verbose output in the console. For this option to appear you have to click on the `Advanced...` button under the drop down with server names and you should see something like this:

[image: Enabling verbose output]

Once you have done that instead of a mere:

```
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Could not create or change to directory. Directory [var]]
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
```

you may see something like this:

```
SSH: Connecting from host [some.host]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [Some Configuration] ...
SSH: Creating session: username [user], hostname [x.x.x.x], port [22]
SSH: Connecting session ...
...
SSH: cd [/var/lib/module/]
SSH: OK
SSH: mkdir [var]
SSH: FAILED: Message [Permission denied]
```

This should give you a clue of what may be wrong.

In your case you are not explicitly creating any directory but if you toggle the help tip for `Remote directory` field you will see this:

```
Optional destination folder.

This folder will be below the one in the global configuration, if present.
The folder will be created if does not exist.
```

This would indicate that the location you try to `pwd` in does not exist and the plugin is helpfully trying to create it for you but your user has no permissions to do so.

While the user permissions may be a problem, if you are certain that the directory exists and none should be created then check the global settings in:

```
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Publish over SSH
```

and take a look at the `Remote Directory` field:

[image]

Let's say there is `/home/sophie` specified there then the plugin will try to send your files to `/home/sophie/var/www/html` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the user home directory was not created using the command
**useradd user_name** I had use bellow command to make everything works
OS: Debian Linux

```
useradd -m dockeradmin
ls -la /home/dockeradmin/
passwd dockeradmin
usermod -aG docker dockeradmin
```