# Unable to deploy SpringBoot jar in ec2 through jenkins?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

[SSH-SERVER Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyELV.png)
[SSH-CONFIG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chCzE.png)
I am trying to deploy jar in my ec2 through jenkins ,This is What I have Configured
please find the Image attached

But I am getting err as

```
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [127]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
```

I am not sure if Exec command is correct to deploy jar

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is a similar case with yours. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544560/send-build-artifacts-over-ssh-could-not-create-directory).

It is suggested to enable verbose output in the console if you use Publish Over SSH Plugin. Then you are able to find a clue with details logs.